# View Detail window does not expand Collection properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I have a small issue with visual studio.
I have a method that throws a CustomException

If I wrap the code that calls this method in a try/catch I can see the exception details in the debugger

[image]

if I remove the try/catch I can see that the "errors" property has Count=4 but I cannot see the errors...

[image]

Is this expected or is it a bug?
I'm using vs2015 enterprise and .NET 4.5.2

You can easily reproduce it:
1)Create a class library with this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public static class Class1
    {
        public static void DoSomethingThatThrowsException()
        {
            throw new MyException(Enumerable.Range(1, 4).Select(e => new MyError() { Message = "error " + e.ToString() }).ToList());
       }
    }

    public class MyException : Exception
    {
        public IEnumerable<MyError> errors { get; set; }
        public MyException(IEnumerable<MyError> theErrors) { errors = theErrors; }
    }
    public class MyError { public string Message { get; set; } }
}
```

2)Create a console app with this:

```
using ClassLibrary1;

namespace ConsoleApplicationException
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Class1.DoSomethingThatThrowsException();
            }
            catch (MyException ex)
            {
                //Here I can expand ex.errors;
            }

            //Here I can see that Count=4 but I cannot see the errors...
            Class1.DoSomethingThatThrowsException(); 

        }
    }
}
```

PS
I can solve my problem using the "DebuggerDisplay" Attribute,I'm just wondering why Visual Studio doesn't work as expected

```
[DebuggerDisplay("FullDetails = {FullDetails}")]
public class MyException : Exception
{
    public IEnumerable<MyError> errors { get; set; }
    public MyException(IEnumerable<MyError> theErrors) { errors = theErrors;         }
    public string FullDetails { get { return string.Join(",", errors.Select(e => e.Message)); } }
}
```

**Update**
If I change my List to Array,I have the same problem,but if I change it to Dictionary I can see the first record!!!

Comment: Maybe the `MyError` class isn't (marked as) serializable?

Comment: @UweKeim I have the same problem even if I mark it as Serializable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine in Visual Studio 2017...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that for some reason compiler can't evaluate the LINQ query when you throw it. Try to create it and then throw it. It will allow you to calculate the LINQ query before you throw it:

```
 public static void DoSomethingThatThrowsException()
 {
     var ex = new MyException(Enumerable.Range(1, 4)
                              .Select(e => new MyError() 
                                           { 
                                              Message = "error " + e.ToString() 
                                           })
                              .ToList());
     throw ex;
 }
```